# Ensure that a particular value is submitted with every form / AJAX request

Tags: jsf-2

Is there any way to ensure that, along with any other fields that are being submitted, one particular field (a hidden input) on the page is submitted with every form / AJAX submission? For example, if I have

```
<input type="hidden" id="submitted-value" value="some value"/>
```

somewhere on the page, and another form, say

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{someBean.value}"/>
</h:form>
```

Is there any way of modifying the submitted data before it is submitted to include the `submitted-value` field?

Comment: What is the use-case for which you think this is the required solution?

Comment: Mocking out a client window ID-like solution for a limited couple of pages until the JBoss EAP catches up with JSF 2.2